# How to improve SEO ranking of keyword with least content on the webpage?

Tags: seo, keywords, ranking

I have a challenge to rank my page for few keywords. But the dilemma is my page is bound to have very less content being a chat login page. On top of it my page is not the primary page of parent site, though it is placed on entirely different domain URL. Now since the density of my expected keywords is less on my page due to less content, it is definitely affecting my ranking and at the same time I see my parent site has various portals revolving around those keywords which is giving them the higher rank than what my page has. To counter this, I opbserve/conclude below points:

1. I have to change my page design to have more content so that I can increase my key word density
2. I may try to have some content invisible on the page to get the high density(no sure if google will like it)
3. Revise my criteria to decide which are the less competitive keywords. (Currently, I visualize what would be the other ways of querying the problem user is facing to get to my website.)

I need some expert advice, on how can I go ahead with this situation?

Comment: Rule 1 is stop reading out SEO books. Keywords do not need to appear on the page in order for you to rank, since all major search engines use external signals as well as internal, in fact... external signals hold the most weight. I would however recommend that you use the keyword in both the meta description and the title, but with that said... you don't need that either with enough 'good' external signals.

Comment: @SimonHayter Those were the Golden Words.. could you elaborate on External Signals please?? Also suggest me some place online or a reference where I can actually learn something close to your knowledge :)

Comment: There's a lot but in short external signals are backlinks, brand mentions, social buzz, local business factors etc. Furthermore it should be dearly noted that pages such as terms and conditions, contact us, about us, privacy policy and other internal pages add 'relevancy' to the domain which can also support thin pages.

Comment: Rule 2 is read SEO books. Preferably up-to-date ones, as they will give you the best insights to solve your problem.

Comment: @SandyLee your first statement is the absolute opposite to the first statement of first comment made by SimonHayter .. what to do?? Read books or not?? If yes, then please recommend few...

Comment: Never stop reading, and make sure you read up-to-date information. SEO isn't easy and changes very quickly. What Simon is saying is correct, keywords don't have to appear on pages but they do help. I would start with reading this https://moz.com/blog

Comment: Oh for Christ sake! Quite nearly all online SEO advice is pure B.S. Stop reading the bull. Search is not about keywords and never really was. It is a myth. It is about whole language. Do you know what happens when you try and social engineer search engines? You get cr@p. You are not smarter than 70,000 engineers using AI machine learning trying to study how people think, speak, and search. Just create your website for users and stop trying to control how you think your site should be found and just let it be found naturally. Please.

Comment: I am advising not participating in the keyword chase. It is a complete waste of time. Most SEOs are not technical people. You cannot black box test a search engine to reverse engineer how they work. The system is far to complicated for that. SEOs like to black box test and hypothesize. Black box testing only works for simpler processes. Instead, read about how SEs work from engineers. Not SEOs. Search is about being found how you should be found. If you try and game the system you will get very poor results. Be natural. It will work out okay. Cheers!!

Comment: See also: [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)  You need to use keywords in the title and prominently on the page, however Google understands synonyms and topics.  Rankings won't come from stuffing in keywords. After minimal keyword work, you need to pay attention to reputation and usability. Your rankings will come over time from, links, click through rate, social proof, site speed, and ultimately the ability to satisfy users.

Comment: @SandyLee There is not a single PDF, book or any 'one' page published that covers SEO entirely, the ones that attempt to supply a endless supply of horse manure, hence the 'ditch the SEO books' comment. MOZ is considered a SEO resource and undoubtedly a great one to say the least, but unlike a book, it has hundreds of different authors and different opinions. Some articles are better than others, particularly those published by Rand Fishkin. My point is...SEO books are rubbish, paper ones are produced for sales and digital ones are mostly click baits.

Comment: @SimonHayter but this way newbies will end up nowhere!! Only the google provided guidelines on how a html should be, will work for optimum results, what would be “that thing” on which a newbie rely on, to learn? Experience, would again be dependent on the knowledge, right? Please put some insight..

Comment: @OMTheEternity That s why you come here - to know the truth! [Insert grin here] Pleas ask anything here. We will set you straight. We are here to help. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc thats a classic example of verbal backlinking to webmasters ;-) clever..

Comment: Get a good SEO score is easy, What there is hard are using word that people use and other big websites dosn’t use so you dont have to end on page 3 becouse click. You can use Google SEO tools to help you see what your website score is and how to get it better. E.g my website score is 95 while Apple is 92, Apple get first in the search resultat becouse of millions of click

Answer (score 3):

You can not simply rank a login page for a few keywords without context, the login page should not be your main page. Think about it, as an user I will be abducted from my searching experience to land in a page that will raise more questions rather than answering them.

Create some context on the chat environment, build a funnel and make sure people searching for X will understand what to do, what is it for and what will be their benefits. That’s how you rank.

Do not think meta title and description tags will make your page rank, use them to grab people's attention which in return will give you better rankings.

Do not make content invisible period

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to accomplish isn't necessarily a very good strategy, depending on what kind of keywords you are trying to rank for.

If you are trying to rank for "cheesecake recipe" and just keyword stuff a lot of cheesecake keywords onto the page your entire site could even get hit with a keyword stuffing penalty. The page has nothing to do with cheesecakes and you're trying to rank for something you shouldn't be ranking for.

If on the other hand you're trying to rank your login page for "example brand login", that is fine. That is what the page is about and it should rank for it.

Google isn't going to rank pages solely based on keyword density. You can't just stuff keywords all over the place and expect to rise to the top. When a person searches for "cheesecake recipe", Google is going to show pages that it thinks has the absolute best recipes posted on it. It's not going to show your login page almost regardless of what you do.

If you want your login page to rank for a keyword like "cheesecake recipe" then you literally have no choice but to put an amazing cheesecake recipe on the page and then you have a chance. Your h1, title, density and other signals will almost certainly not rank you for this. You need the correct content and good backlinks help.

If you use invisible content trying to trick Googlebot you might as well get a min wage job, cause you can expect to get your site completely deindexed. Google doesn't reward people for trying to trick its bot.

Just make good content for the keywords you are trying to rank for. Google wants to show the absolute best page on the web for what a person is searching for. If you can make the best content then all you can do is hope that Google agrees.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your first option is OK, it takes time.
2. Second, you are right. Google don't like invisible text.
3. The third is OK too. Find less used words for your website.

You can try to write some blog and articles to send people to your page. It also improves ranking of your domain. 
At first, start with `<title>, meta description` then you can try put it some `<h1>` and `<alt>` in image.

Changing domain in your case probably don't help you.

Comment: Can you be more specific here?

Answer (score 1):

1. According to https://www.searchmetrics.com/ Having keywords in a variety of places can help such as:

   - Title
   - H1
   - Body
   - URL
   - H2-H4
   - Meta Description
   - Anchor text
   - IMG Tags
2. Invisible words will be picked up and Google will move you lower in the search rankings. Don't do this
3. There are lots of tools to help you come up with keywords you hadn't thought of before. There are very good paid ones but a good place to start might just be Google trends as this gives related queries and related topics to a search.

Comment: Perfect example of SEO outdated advice written over a decade ago. Google and Bing can rank pages without meeting any of those e.g PDF files have zero HTML markup and no equivalent code meanwhile they can rank just as well.

Comment: @SimonHayter is perfectly correct. It is the content that search uses to make matches. Adding keywords in various places only confuses things. Why? Because your list is a list of signals giving clues to what the page is about and are not ranking factors. It supports the content itself with clues that may or may not exist. It is better from a search engines point of view not to rely upon variable data and rely upon the content itself.

Comment: Are you saying this advice doesn't work? This is the technique used by my company and following these sort of methods has led to ranking improvements. What should we do differently?

Comment: Movement maybe...  a surge in rankings? doubtful. I would guess that you have improved the site in other areas and not just what you have listed.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the log-in page ranks for brand terms (and assuming there is no penalty on your site you will) then you're fine.

If you want to extend the reach of the site build content targeting generic terms 'around' the log-in page and funnel users in.

Create consistent user journeys that target your user's search intent. That is what SEO is about, and what it should always have been about really. The real value-add is figuring out what your user's intent before they know it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have to need to do anything from the points you mentioned.

you can change the design if you don't like but no need for ranking.

and now google becomes smarter than ever before. google ranks for those keywords also which you have not written on your page. so no need for increased density

think about e-commerce sites when you have a page with no content. Coupon sites, product selling sites have not much content to add keywords but they rank higher than their competitors.

Because they use A Right SEO Strategy to rank higher.

first of all, check your keyword details. Its Volume, KD, and much more.

then check its competitor in Google. (their content, Backlink Profile and other weak points) Use https://ahrefs.com

then think how you can better.

and copy their backlinks, Add Keywords in your Title and Meta, Img Alt texts, Interlink you that page from your site where you can...

And make Good User Experience.